# LookupError: No gradient defined for operation type: ResizeNearestNeighborGrad

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to add [Wasserstein gradient penalty](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00028) into loss calculation of discriminator. Without adding this penalty everything works fine. But when this part is being added, It gives an error something similar to this:

```
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 737, in _GradientsHelper
        (op.name, op.type))
      LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'gradients/discriminator/decoder/ResizeNearestNeighbor_grad/ResizeNearestNeighborGrad' (op type: ResizeNearestNeighborGrad)
```

Here is the part of the source code which is used to calculate Wasserstein gradient penalty:

```
    differences = tf.subtract(images_fake, images_real)
    alpha_shape = [params.batch_size] + [1] * (differences.shape.ndims - 1)
    alpha = tf.random_uniform(shape=alpha_shape, minval=0., maxval=1.)
    interpolates = images_real + (alpha * differences)
    d_model = Model(params, args.mode, interpolates, reuse_variables, images_fake, 1)
    gradients = tf.gradients(d_model.logistic_linear, [interpolates])[0]
    slopes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(gradients), reduction_indices=[1]))
    gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean((slopes - 1.) ** 2)
    _gradient_penalty = 10 * gradient_penalty
```

But it throw above mentioned error when below line is bening executing.

```
   d_optim = opt_discriminator_step.minimize(total_loss_discriminator, var_list=d_vars)
```

Still, I have a no clue how to get on with this issue. Any comments or answers are welcome.

Comment: The problem is that your model uses (among other things) tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor, then computes the gradients and tries to apply a minimization based (among other things) on those gradients. But the gradient of `tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor` is an op `ResizeNearestNeighborGrad` that does not have a defined gradient in TensorFlow (it's not that it's not possible to implement, but the TF team does not implement gradients of gradient operations...). A possible solution might be to implement the resize "by hand" with simpler ops...

Comment: Nah tbh I'm thinking unless the resizing is really simple (integer width and height factors) trying to emulate the `resize_nearest_neighbor` op by hand ([see implementation here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.10.1/tensorflow/core/kernels/resize_nearest_neighbor_op.cc)) would probably be too complicated and inefficient.

Comment: Yeap, I am going to use `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`. Let's see how it will be. Thanks for the comment. I make an issue as well. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22208

Comment: Note however that your problem is not that you cannot get the gradient of the resizing operation (`tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor` / `tf.image.resize_bicubic`, ops `ResizeNearestNeighbor` / `ResizeBilinear`), but that you cannot get the gradient of the gradient of that operation (ops `ResizeNearestNeighborGrad` / `ResizeBilinearGrad`). The existing implementation that you refer to is for the gradient of the resizing (e.g. the gradient of the op `ResizeBilinear` is implemented using the op `ResizeBilinearGrad`), not for the gradient of the gradient (`ResizeBilinearGrad` has no gradient).

Comment: yeap I get it. It took me for a while to understand where when wrong.

Comment: @jdehesa why is tf trying to compute gradient of gradient?

Comment: @AlexKreimer In this case, OP was implementing a particular kind of loss function that used gradient values in its calculation. That means that, in order to optimise the model, as you have to take the gradient of the loss wrt the model variables, in this case it would require calculating the gradient of that gradient. This is something that can be done in many cases, but here (at least at the time this question was posted) TF did not know how to calculate the gradient of the gradient of the operation `tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor` used by the model, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D .It can perform the same thing ,just make sure to set correctly the parameters

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).